# Is there a way to create promise that resolves when Google Maps Javascript API is loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, promise, deferred

Google Maps Javascript API is supposed to be loaded [this way](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#The_Hello_World_of_Google_Maps_v3):

```
<script>
  function initMap() {
    console.log('loaded');
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

If I had to answer my question, I'd do it like so:

```
var googleAPILoadedPromise = Promise.pending();
function initMap() {
  googleAPILoadedPromise.resolve();
}
googleAPILoadedPromise.promise.then(function() {
  console.log('loaded');
});
```

But deferreds are deprecated and possibly considered an anti-pattern, at least in [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/f85cf33368abd7407c2e744c6ff6f85b16be3c8b/src/promise.js#L751). Is there any better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On second thought, I'd do it like this:

```
<script>
  var resolvePromise = null;
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolvePromise = resolve;
  });
  promise.then(function() {
    console.log('loaded');
  });
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=resolvePromise" async defer></script>
```

Comment: I don't know why this works, but it works great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Probably like this:

```
<script>
  var loadGoogleMaps = (function(root, d, x, cb){
    var s = d.createElement(x)
    var a = d.getElementsByTagName(x)[0]
    var cleanup = function (done) {
      return function (value) {
        s.remove()
        delete root[cb]
        return done(value)
      }
    }
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
      root[cb] = cleanup(resolve)
      s.onerror = cleanup(reject)
      s.async = true
      s.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=' + cb
      a.parentNode.insertBefore(s,a)
    });
  })(this, document, 'script', 'googleMapsCallback' + Date.now())
  loadGoogleMaps.then(function(){
    console.log('loaded')
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Typescript solution. Remove async and defer which waits till js loads.

Put in index.html

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

make function global, reference anywhere in project.

```
export function initMap(callback): Promise<any> {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // SEE IF IN WINDOW OBJECT
      callback(resolve);
   });
}
```

To reference global file, follow below.

```
import { initMap } from 'path to initMap';

initMap().then((res) => {
  console.log('map: ' + res);
});
```

Comment: It's 1 line longer than my current solution, considering `console.log`. Then, how do I even make it work? My browser doesn't run typescript natively. Not to mention that it doesn't work as intended. The promise gets resolved before the library is loaded. Correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Comment: There are 2 things that are wrong with your answer. 1. It's not clear how to make it [work](https://jsfiddle.net/xyuri/kac2Lf6s/1/). 2. If my browser would suddenly run typescript natively, the script wouldn't work as expected. The promise would be resolved before the library is loaded.

Comment: Okay, now we have two major issues: 1. You're relying on undocumented behavior (`if (google && google.maps)`). 2. If `initMap()` is called before the library is loaded, `console.log(...)` would never be called. And a couple of minor ones: 1. The docs recommend using `async` and `defer`. That should be the default course of action, unless there's a reason not to follow the documentation. 2. No need to pass anything to `resolve()` and `reject()`.